# What will be the value of $3/1!+5/2!+7/3!+...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What will be the value of $3/1!+5/2!+7/3!+...$?

I'm trying to bring it in terms of $e$.Is it possible?

I used taylor series for e.

Comment: Hint:  write each term as $\frac {2n+1}{n!}=\frac 2{(n-1)!}+\frac 1{n!}$

Comment: @lulu you beat me to it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can write it as follow:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}\right) = \\
= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{2}{(n-1)!}\right) +\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right) = \\
= 2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right) +\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right) - 1 = 3e - 1,$$

where of course $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right) = e.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{2k+1}{k!}=2\frac1{(k-1)!}+\frac{1}{k!}$